# Pass Current Eloquent into getXAttribute in Model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have create a `getIsAdminAttribute` that returns boolean and it works if I use `Auth::user()` however, now I need to pass the User object into this method so that I can check if given user is admin.

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

    public function getIsAdminAttribute()
    {   
       if (Admin::where('user_id', $user->id)->first()) {
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I pass the `$user` into this method, so that I can call it like:

`$user->is_admin` and it returns boolean.

---

If I try this, it returns null.

```
getIsAdminAttribute($user) {
   dd($user);
}
```

Comment: Is the `$user` object always the current user or do you have to be able to use other user objects as well?

Comment: I want to use other user objects as well. (If I use `Auth::user()->id` it works for the current user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in the `User` model, so you can use `$this` to access the properties of the current object.

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{   
   return Admin::where('user_id', $this->id)->count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :) If this solved your problem, please consider marking this as the solution so other developers might find this answer.